# Code launched from command-line: graphic device blank

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, device, graphic

I have a code that has to work from command-line. If I run it piece by piece from RStudio it works properly. When I run it from command-line, it does open the graphic device, but it remain blank.

```
require(ggplot2)
#ds <- head(SOM_dist_tot)
num <- 6
ds <- c(1.00566799, 0.81354614, 0.36507594, 0.15541231, 0.13957369, 0.06986632)

vett <- as.data.frame(ds)
pdf("ggplot_test.pdf")
  gioele <-ggplot(vett, aes(x= as.numeric(rownames(vett)), y =vett$ds))+
           geom_point(size=2) + xlab("X") + ylab("Y")+
           ggtitle("...")+
           theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=-45, hjust=0, vjust=1), 
                 plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm"), 
                 plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold", colour = "black", vjust = -1))
  #print(gioele)
  plot(gioele)
dev.off()

print(gioele)

inputFromUser <- as.numeric(readLines(file("stdin"),1))

dev.off()
```

I want to show the graph "gioele", such to give informations to the user. Then the user choose a command to insert (`inputFromUser`), and then the window has to close.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Maybe look into [ggsave](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.2.1/ggsave.html)? Why are you using plot(gg2), is it not supposed to be print(gg2)?

Comment: I have tried a lot of possible combinations. I've tried plot(gg2), print(gg2), only gg2 (in that case it is ignored and the windows doesn't pop-up). I take a look on ggsave and I'll let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of pain I have understood the problem: it is a conflict between readLines() and the graphic device. Inother words, it correctly open the device plotting the graph, but then the readLines(...) make the graphic device blank (I don't know how it is technically possible).

I have found the solution removing the readLines() and using a more correct `readline()`.

```
require(ggplot2)
#ds <- head(SOM_dist_tot)
num <- 6
ds <- c(1.00566799, 0.81354614, 0.36507594, 0.15541231, 0.13957369, 0.06986632)


pdf("plot_test.pdf")
  plot(ds[1:num], type="p", xlab="X", ylab="Y", col="red")
  title(main="...", sub = "...", line=-1.2, cex.sub = 0.75, font.sub = 3, col.sub = "red")
dev.off()
#cat("Faccio il plot")
# plot(ds[1:num], type="p", xlab="X", ylab="Y", col="red")
# title(main="...", sub = "...", line=-1.2, cex.sub = 0.75, font.sub = 3, col.sub = "red")


vett <- as.data.frame(ds)
pdf("ggplot_test.pdf")
  gg2 <-ggplot(vett, aes(x= as.numeric(rownames(vett)), y =vett$ds))+
    geom_point(size=2) + xlab("X") + ylab("Y")+
    ggtitle("...")+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=-45, hjust=0, vjust=1), 
          plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "cm"), 
          plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold", colour = "black", vjust = -1))
  #print(gg2)
  plot(gg2)
dev.off()

print(gg2)

#inputFromUser <- as.numeric(readLines(file("stdin"),1))
inputFromUser <- as.numeric(readline())

dev.off()
```